# TFS Solution Explorer missing checkout icon

Tags: tfs

I recently upgraded `TFS server` from **2013** to **2018.2**

Developer with VS2013 can't check-out file from Solution Explorer, but this developer can check-out the same file from Source Control Explorer.
What is the reason and how to fix?

Log window: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: workspace

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the problem was with the workspace, as I created new workspace (on the same PC) and I could check-out the file from Solution Explorer

Thanks!